# vNext Selecting Main Method for Entry

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

I'm not seeing any documentation for this, but it looks like in vNext, you can happily compile and run an application with non-static method `void Main()`.  Actually, a new Console Application template gives you a non-static Main.  For example:

```
public class Program
{
    public Guid MyGuid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World {0}", MyGuid);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

`MyGuid` is instantiated and is a non-empty Guid here.  So I'm assuming it creates an instance of my Program class and goes from there.

My question is when I have two `Mains`:

```
public class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("main no args");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("main with args {0}", string.Join(", ",args));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

In the project properties, I gave arguments `arg1` and `arg2`.  However, my console displays `main no args` when I run it.  If I remove the argument-less `Main`, I get the expected output `main with args arg1, arg2`.

Now, if I switch the order of the methods in the code, my `Main` with arguments is hit.  If I remove the arguments, my `Main` with arguments is *still* hit, printing `main with args`.

I'd like some clarification on how Roslyn is selecting my `Main` exactly.  Is it always the first one?  I'm sure this is documented, but I can't find it.

**Edit**

If I change my class name to something besides `Program`, my Console Application runs, and immediately crashes telling me I don't have a suitable entry point.  So my best guess is `the first Main method in the Program class`

Comment: Not sure I understand the "too broad" close vote. This is a very narrowly-focused question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is absolutely right. The relevant code from the K Runtime is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common/Impl/EntryPointExecutor.cs).

Essentially, if you don't have a static main method, the runtime looks for a type called "Program" with one or more `Main` methods, instantiates it and calls the first one.

This is also touched on [here](http://alxandr.me/2014/06/30/loading-all-of-the-things/):

> Then, a class named Program is searched for, and a Main method is looked up. If the Main method is static, it's invoked as is, otherwise an instance of Program is created using the DI, and Main is invoked on the instance. At this point our program is run.

Comment: it appears you *have* to be in the Program class.  That description is exactly what I'm seeing.  It's the first `Main` method regardless of arguments or if it's static.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have vNext here, but my guess is that this is similar to the current Visual Studio, in that in the project settings you can choose the startup object, and method in the property pages.  Have you looked there?

It looks like vNext has moved startup to a delegate type, probably just a standard `Action` or `Action<TArgs>`

EDIT:

Well, as it turns out, as with many things in the newer version of .NET, it's based on convention.  We see similar things with OWIN as well.